# Change div id on each do loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Im using a bootstrap collapse item and have the code set up like this:

```
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1"><%= task.title %><p style="text-align:right;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></p></a>
          <p class="taskdescription"><%= task.description %></p>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <% task.subtasks.each do |subtask| %>
            <li class="list-group-item"><%= subtask.title %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Which is outputting the correct list but with each item i need to increment the value of the div:

```
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
```

to

```
<div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
```

then

```
<div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
```

and so on until each item is displayed from the collection.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `each_with_index do |element, index| do ....`

This was you have access to the element index and can use it as any rails variable.

```html
 <% @tasks.each_with_index do |task, index| %>
        <div class="panel-group">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1"><%= task.title %><p style="text-align:right;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></p></a>
                <p class="taskdescription"><%= task.description %></p>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse<%= index +1 %>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="list-group">
                <% task.subtasks.each do |subtask| %>
                  <li class="list-group-item"><%= subtask.title %></li>
                <% end %>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can loop with `each.with_index(1)` and use the counter variable `i` to dynamically append the counter on the generated html.

```
<% @tasks.each.with_index(1) do |task, i| %>
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      ...
      <div id="collapse#{i}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```